# Using Flask and Jython under Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, flask, windows-7, jython-2.7

**Hello everyone,**

So I have been trying to use Jython to connect to an API Rest and retrieve some information. Now I want to use the Flask Framework with it. I have been trying to install the Flask with Jython but it does not seem to work at all. I am working on a Windows 7 machine and the problem for me is also that I can not download directly from the internet. For all other framework I used python wheels and installed these with Jython which worked fine.

I already tried to following commands and got these errors:

- First error that I got was that it could not find the '**init**.py' file in the flask folder so I changed the path in the file to the total path. But it just continued to give me more errors.
- jython -m pip install '*.whl
  [Screenshot of the command line ouput of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuZBc.png)
- pip install '*.whl (same as above)

I am a little stuck here and I hope that someone has an idea on how to solve this problem.

**Big thanks already!!**

Comment: Why do you need Jython specifically? Why not use normal CPython?

Comment: Because I am going to integrate another function to an already existing Framework which has these requirements! I am trying to find a solution but if it really does not work, I will try to use CPython. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with Jython 2.7.0. See [this error report in pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2979) and [this one in Jython](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2521).

The second of those indicates that it is fixed in the 2.7.1 release candidate.

Comment: Also I had another error while installing MarkupSafe from "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MarkupSafe" . No matter what I tried, it will not install. There is no wheel online so I downloaded the tar.gz file and unpacked it. Then I tried 'jython setup.py install' which gave me the error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'markupsafe/__init__.py' . Hope that you can help me on this as well. Still using Windows 7 but now Jython 2.7.1